# Keras 2 code is executing keras 1 compatibility code

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to run an example that uses keras/tensorflow. I am using Keras 2.0.8.
When I write this simple code:

```
from keras.layers import ZeroPadding2D
pad = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), data_format=None)
```

and try to debug `ZeroPadding2D` I am directed to a file named `convolutional.py` which contains statement as `@interfaces.legacy_zeropadding2d_support`. I am a bit lost there but I think this is a compatibility code for keras 1.
I checked the keras 1 and 2 definition of `ZeroPadding2D`:

```
# keras 1
keras.layers.convolutional.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), dim_ordering='default') 

# keras 2
keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), data_format=None)
```

- since my import is explicitly referring to keras 2 (it does not include any `convolutional` in the import) and
- my function call is also keras 2 specific as it contains `data_format` parameter should I be directed to a keras 2 implementation?

What am I missing here? I know there is special care with *compatibility interfaces* as mentioned in [here](https://blog.keras.io/introducing-keras-2.html) for running keras 1 code inside keras 2 but is something in my (tiny) code that is keras 1?

I am relatively new to python (if not obvious) and I am debugging using pyCharm if this makes a difference.

So, how am I suppose to run just keras 2 code and secondly what am I missing in the situation above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is Keras 2, it's everything OK with it.

Although you import the layer from `keras.layers`, internally it's imported from `keras.layers.convolutional`. You can inspect keras 2.0.8 code, and there is no `ZeroPadding2D` in the [`layers` folder](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/2.0.8/keras/layers). It will be found only in the `convolutional.py`. The `__init__` file is responsible for automatically importing the layers inside the other files.

Now, that `@interfaces.legacy...` line is called a "decorator", it adds some extra functionality to the method where it appears. It's on top of a genuine keras 2 code to handle the possibility of the user trying to input keras 1 arguments.

The code you see there is keras 2. And you can look at the [legacy.interface](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/2.0.8/keras/legacy/interfaces.py/#L520) and see what this decorator adds.

It adds the possibility of using the old `dim_ordering` instead of `data_format`, and it makes the proper conversions from the old values of `dim_ordering`, which where `tf` and `th` to the new values, `channels_last` and `channels_first`.

Comment: So, basically keras 2 has changed just the definition but not the implementation which remains keras 1?

Comment: It has only the keras 2 implementation. But if you call it with keras 1 arguments, it will adjust itself to keras 2. (Maybe they changed it, maybe not, but I don't know).